# What is a simple and safe way to choose a random enum value?

Tags: random, enums, nim-lang

I needed to choose a random value from an enum. In some article about Nim
I found this solution:

```nim
import random

type Animal = enum
  Cat
  Dog
  Cow

echo rand(0..2).Animal
```

But this doesn't scale well: If some values are added to or removed from the
enum, we have to adjust the upper number.

We can even get a runtime error:

```nim
import random

type Animal = enum
  Cat
  Dog

randomize(123)

while true:
  echo rand(0..2).Animal
```

```
Cat
Cat
Dog
…/example.nim(10) example
…/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.4.4/lib/system/fatal.nim(49) sysFatal
Error: unhandled exception: value out of range: 2 notin 0 .. 1 [RangeDefect]
```

I am looking for a simple way to choose a random value from an enum<sup>1</sup>
that is safe, meaning that if it compiles, it is guaranteed that there will be
no `RangeDefect` or similar runtime error.

I would also be interested to know if there is a compiler setting that
generates at least a warning in the above example.

The compiler seems to be capable of this in principle:

```
Animal(5)

→ Error: 5 can't be converted to Animal
```

After reading in https://nim-lang.org/docs/random.html about

- [rand,Rand,range[]](https://nim-lang.org/docs/random.html#rand%2CRand%2Crange%5B%5D)
- [rand,Rand,HSlice[T: Ordinal or float or float32 or float64,T: Ordinal or float or float32 or float64]](https://nim-lang.org/docs/random.html#rand%2CRand%2CHSlice%5BT%3A+Ordinal+or+float+or+float32+or+float64%2CT%3A+Ordinal+or+float+or+float32+or+float64%5D)
- [rand,HSlice[T: Ordinal or float or float32 or float64,T: Ordinal or float or float32 or float64]](https://nim-lang.org/docs/random.html#rand%2CHSlice%5BT%3A+Ordinal+or+float+or+float32+or+float64%2CT%3A+Ordinal+or+float+or+float32+or+float64%5D)
- [rand,typedesc[T]](https://nim-lang.org/docs/random.html#rand%2Ctypedesc%5BT%5D)

I thought that one of the following could work, but they don't compile:

```
rand(Animal)

→ Error: type mismatch: got <type Animal>
```

```
rand(range(Animal))

→ Error: type mismatch: got <type Animal> but expected 'range = range (None)'
```

```
rand(range[Animal])

→ Error: expected range
```

```
rand(Slice[Animal])

→ Error: type mismatch: got <type Slice[example.Animal]>
```

```
rand(Slice(Animal))

→ Error: type mismatch: got <type Animal> but expected 'Slice = CompositeTypeClass'
```

This does work, but I guess it is unnecessarily inefficient, because it needs
to allocate and fill a sequence:

```nim
import sequtils

echo sample(Animal.toSeq)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm assuming no enums with holes, which I'm aware are
[another issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/13980).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A straightforward solution is to use [`low`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#low,typedesc%5BT%5D) and [`high`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#high,typedesc%5BT%5D):

```nim
rand(Animal.low..Animal.high)
```

Using a generic proc allows to write `rand(Animal)`:

```nim
import random

type Animal = enum
  Cat
  Dog
  Cow

proc rand(T: typedesc): T =
  rand(T.low..T.high)

randomize(123)

for _ in 1..6:
  echo rand(Animal)
```

Output:

```
Cat
Cat
Dog
Cow
Cow
Dog
```

Comment: just wanted to add that this won't compile for an enum with holes, addressing your safety concern.  here you're using rand(HSlice[Animal])